# Wildcards in getElementsByTagName (xml.dom.minidom)

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a ODF-document with xml.dom.minidom. I would like to get all elements that are text:p OR text:h. Seems like there would be a way to add a wildcard in the getElementsByTagName method. Or is it?

Is there a better way to parse a odf-document without uno?

Answer (score 0):

As getElementsByTagName returns a DOMElement list you could just simply concatenate the two lists.

Alternatively XPath supports `and/or` operators, so you could use that. That would require using the `elementTree` or `lxml` modules instead.

Comment: But I would need them in the same order as in the tree. If I concenate them the right order will be lost. That leaves me to try the other libraries?

Comment: assuming that there's is a one to one mapping between the text:p and text:h you could use the python zip function to create a list of tuples, so that the tuples would consist of the corresponding elements text:h and text:p elements.

Comment: Ok. I rather try lxml, I think... :) Thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
root_element.getElementsByTagNameNS('text', '*')
```

maybe put `?` instead of `*`

this worked for me, but the other way around

```
<325t4342:Key> fooo </.....>...

key = (root_element.getElementsByTagNameNS('*', "Key")[0]).firstChild.data.strip()
```

gives me "foo"